# Configure logstash to take updated values

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have connected logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana. It all works fine.

I used logstash to take the tomcat logs.

```
input {
file {
    path => "/tom_logs/*"
    type => "tomcat"
    start_position => "end"
}
}
```

Once i updated the log file, It takes the whole logs in the file instead of updated log. I just want to load the log which is last updated.

Any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Logstash creates a sincedb-file to maintain the position for every input file. It's usually `$HOME/.sincedb`. You should check whether this file is created/can be created.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a bit strange because I never experienced it. To be sure that I understand correctly : when a new log comes, logstash start analysing again all the logs in the file ?

You correctly specify the `start_position=>"end"` which is actually the default option. In this case, logstash must consider only new changes in the file (so, new logs) since its start-up.

So, I think the issue of this "bug" is not in logstash but in "how" tomcat writes logs... But if I were you, I'd try to specify `path=>"tom_logs/*.log"` instead of `*` only.

Hope it will help.